# Can't pass extra form data with radio button data to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple form I have a radio button and 2 hidden fields.  I want to pass the radio button value and the hidden fields value via ajax to a php page.  The radio button value passes fine but not the hidden fields do not.  I have hard coded the the values for table and id in the php page to make sure the value of the radio button is being passed for testing.

```
<input type="radio" name="contract" value="0" class="custom-switch-input">
<input type="radio" name="contract" value="1" class="custom-switch-input">
<input type="radio" name="contract" value="2" class="custom-switch-input">

<input type="hidden" name="table" value="timber_sales">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="177">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var contract = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
             url:"edit_do.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{contract:contract,id:id,table:table},
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: Aside of missing question in the question text (read: In question tag is not sufficient) what else did you try and failed? Refer to SO questions on SO why they fail to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of contract in your event listener, but not `id` or `table`.

To get this to work, the way you currently have it, you'll need to search the dom for the value of your hidden fields as well.

```
var contract = $(this).val();
var id = $('input[name="id"]').val();
var table = $('input[name="table"]').val();
```

Comment: If the answer I've posted does not suffice, try tagging your question as javascript to see if you get wider array of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values from the hidden fields first. Just like you did with `$(this).val()` for the value of the radio button. So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var contract = $(this).val();
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
        var table = $('input[name=table]').val();

        $.ajax({
             url:"edit_do.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{
               contract: contract,
               id:id,
               table:table
             },
        });
   });
});
```

It is probably better to give the hidden fields an unique ID attribute and get them through `$('#myuniqueid').val()`, but at least the above work as long as you don't have any other fields named ID or table.

Comment: This worked great.  i will changed it to the preferred method as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery event does not know about hidden fields. Try this:

```
            <form id="form1">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="0" class="custom-switch-input">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="1" class="custom-switch-input">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="2" class="custom-switch-input">

                <input type="hidden" name="table" value="timber_sales">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="177">
            </form>
            <form id="form2">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="0" class="custom-switch-input">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="1" class="custom-switch-input">
                <input type="radio" name="contract" value="2" class="custom-switch-input">

                <input type="hidden" name="table" value="timber_sales">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="177">
            </form>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('form').change(function(){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var send = $(this).data();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"edit_do.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:send,
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: One more quick question.  What if I have multiple forms on this same page, different IDs.(While loop from DB) When the user changes a value via a radio button from one of the forms , how can I make sure that form is being used with my previous example?

Comment: This code work only with this form (id=form). If u add another one - nothing happens on change another form.

Comment: How can I change the code to use whatever form the user selects to make the change in?

Comment: Edit answer for this. Now code trigger on change in all forms on a page. If u want to specify actions - use if($(this).id() == 'form1')

Comment: These ids are created fro ma while loop according to how many rows are in the database.  Each from gets next number i.e. form id=1 form id=2 form id=3.  Where would this code go?

Comment: There is no your code about create forms - only for post values from existing, and i cannot help with this, sorry :)